SSH Server Verification Failing - Is Exchange Hash in Correct Form?
I'm writing a simple ssh client in C using the OpenSSL library to handle the Diffie-Hellman operations (big numbers, hashing, computing the shared key, server verification, etc.) I'm running a ssh server on a Kali virtual machine and C client is running on my computer. I've been following the steps specified in RFC 4253 and using Wireshark (on Kali) to help verify that I'm constructing and sending packets to the server correctly, and that I am taking in the server's responses correctly.
For DH, I'm using diffie-hellman-group14-sha256, and for the server's host signature I'm using ssh-ed25519.
I'm stuck on the server verification step. My current guess is that I'm not constructing the exchange hash correctly, but I've run out of issues (I'm aware of) to fix. Here's what I'm currently doing:
RFC 4253 explains how to construct the exchange hash:

C verifies that K_S really is the host key for S (e.g., using  certificates or a local database).  C is also allowed to accept the key without verification; however, doing so will render the protocol insecure against active attacks (but may be desirable for practical reasons in the short term in many environments).  C then computes K = f^x mod p, H = hash(V_C || V_S || I_C || I_S || K_S || e || f || K), and verifies the signature s on H.

The hash H is computed as the HASH hash of the concatenation of the following:

      string    V_C, the client's identification string (CR and LF
                excluded)
      string    V_S, the server's identification string (CR and LF
                excluded)
      string    I_C, the payload of the client's SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
      string    I_S, the payload of the server's SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
      string    K_S, the host key
      mpint     e, exchange value sent by the client
      mpint     f, exchange value sent by the server
      mpint     K, the shared secret

I've been using the SSH types laid out in RFC 4251 to the best of my knowledge, but I may have missed something.
And I've formatted the public host key in accordance to RFC 8709:

6. Signature Format
The "ssh-ed25519" key format has the following encoding:
string
"ssh-ed25519"
string
signature

I think that I'm correctly using the OpenSSL libraries to handle the client's large prime number (p), the client's private key (x), client's public key (e), server's public key (f), and shared secret (K) but I am not sure. Here's the relevant code:
Function to orchestrate DH exchange:
int sendDiffieHellmanExchange(int sock) {
    // init all variables that will need to be freed
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx = NULL, *kctx = NULL, *peerCtx = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY *params = NULL, *clientKey = NULL, *peerkey = NULL;
    BIO *out = NULL;
    BIGNUM *p = NULL, *g = NULL, *eBN = NULL, *fBN = NULL;
    OSSL_PARAM dhParams[3];
    OSSL_PARAM peerParams[4];
    unsigned char *pBin = NULL, *gBin = NULL, *eNetworkOrder = NULL, *buffer = NULL, *serverResponse = NULL;
    int pSize = 0, gSize = 0;
    RawByteArray *e = NULL, *payload = NULL, *packet = NULL;

    // create group 14 parameters with bignum
    p = BN_new();
    BN_get_rfc3526_prime_2048(p);
    g = BN_new();
    BN_set_word(g, 2);

    pSize = BN_num_bytes(p);
    gSize = BN_num_bytes(g);

    // allocate memory for pBin and gBin
    pBin = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(pSize);
    gBin = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(gSize);

    // convert p and g into binary form 
    // need to pad out binary to ensure standard size
    BN_bn2binpad(p, pBin, pSize);
    BN_bn2binpad(g, gBin, gSize);

    // initialize the parameter context for DH key generation 
    pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(NULL, "DH", NULL);

    // prepare the DH parameters (p and g) using OSSL_PARAM array 
    dhParams[0] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_BN("p", pBin, pSize);
    dhParams[1] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_BN("g", gBin, gSize);
    dhParams[2] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_end();

    // use EVP_PKEY_fromdata to create an EVP_PKEY using the DH parameters 
    EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init(pctx);
    EVP_PKEY_fromdata(pctx, &params, EVP_PKEY_KEY_PARAMETERS, dhParams);

    // generate a new DH key
    kctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(params, NULL);
    EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(kctx);
    EVP_PKEY_keygen(kctx, &clientKey);

    // extract the public key BIGNUM
    EVP_PKEY_get_bn_param(clientKey, "pub", &eBN);

    int eLen = BN_num_bytes(eBN);  // get the length of the public key in bytes
    eNetworkOrder = (unsigned char *)malloc(eLen);

    BN_bn2bin(eBN, eNetworkOrder);

    // swap endian-ness from little-endian to big-endian
    eNetworkOrder = swapEndianNess(eNetworkOrder, eLen);
    
    e = addTwosComplementBit(eNetworkOrder, eLen);

    printf("public key (e)\n");
    printf("len of key: %zu\n", e -> size);
    for (int i = 0; i < e -> size; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", e -> data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // building e payload (including prepending size to mpint)
    buffer = malloc(e -> size + 1 + 4);
    buffer[0] = SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT;
    uint32_t mpintLenNetworkOrder = htonl(e->size);
    memcpy(buffer + 1, &mpintLenNetworkOrder, sizeof(uint32_t));
    memcpy(buffer + 5, e -> data, e -> size);

    // store a global copy of e for use in message verification
    eGlobal = malloc(e -> size + sizeof(uint32_t));
    memcpy(eGlobal, &mpintLenNetworkOrder, sizeof(uint32_t));
    memcpy(eGlobal + sizeof(uint32_t), e -> data, e -> size);
    eGlobalLen = e -> size + sizeof(uint32_t);

    payload = malloc(sizeof(RawByteArray));
    assert(payload != NULL);

    payload -> data = buffer;
    payload -> size = e -> size + 1 + 4; // +1 for message code, +4 for mpint len

    packet = constructPacket(payload);

    int sentBytes = send(sock, packet -> data, packet -> size, 0);

    if (sentBytes != -1) {
        printf("Successful DH init send! Number of bytes sent: %i\n", sentBytes);
    } else {
        printf("Send did not complete successfully.\n");
    }
    
    serverResponse = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    memset(serverResponse, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);  // Clear the buffer    
    ssize_t bytesReceived = recv(sock, serverResponse, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    
    if (bytesReceived > 0) {
        // print statement to display the received bytes
    } else {
        printf("No server DH response received :(\n");
        // random error message code
        exit(1);
    }

    ServerDHResponse *dhResponse = extractServerDHResponse(serverResponse);

    // need to store the f from server as global bc OSSL doesnt like the leading 2s complement bit, so we remove it for use within OSSL stuff
    fGlobal = malloc(dhResponse -> fLen + sizeof(uint32_t));
    mpintLenNetworkOrder = htonl(dhResponse -> fLen);
    memcpy(fGlobal, &mpintLenNetworkOrder, sizeof(uint32_t));
    memcpy(fGlobal + sizeof(uint32_t), dhResponse -> f, dhResponse -> fLen);
    fGlobalLen = dhResponse -> fLen + sizeof(uint32_t);

    // importing f into a PKEY:
    
    // If the first byte of f is 0x00 and the length is 257, strip the leading byte.
    // OSSL gets angry in key agreement if there is a leading byte
    if (dhResponse -> fLen == 257 && dhResponse -> f[0] == 0x00) {
        // Create a new buffer to store the adjusted public key
        unsigned char *adjustedF = malloc(dhResponse -> fLen - 1);
        assert(adjustedF != NULL); 

        // Copy the data without the leading zero
        memcpy(adjustedF, dhResponse -> f + 1, dhResponse -> fLen - 1);

        // Update the pointer and length
        free(dhResponse -> f); // Free the old buffer if you dynamically allocated it
        dhResponse -> f = adjustedF; // Point to the new buffer
        dhResponse -> fLen -= 1; // Adjust the length
    }

    fBN = BN_new();
    BN_bin2bn(dhResponse -> f, dhResponse -> fLen, fBN);

    peerCtx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(NULL, "DH", NULL);

    // prepare the parameters for peer's public key
    peerParams[0] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_BN("p", pBin, pSize);  
    peerParams[1] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_BN("g", gBin, gSize); 
    peerParams[2] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_BN("pub", dhResponse -> f, dhResponse -> fLen); 
    peerParams[3] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_end(); 

    EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init(peerCtx);
    EVP_PKEY_fromdata(peerCtx, &peerkey, EVP_PKEY_PUBLIC_KEY, peerParams);

    RawByteArray *k = generateSharedKey(clientKey, peerkey);

    RawByteArray *twosK = addTwosComplementBit(k -> data, k -> size);
    RawByteArray *mpintK = malloc(sizeof(RawByteArray));
    unsigned char *mpintKdata = malloc(twosK -> size + sizeof(uint32_t));
    mpintLenNetworkOrder = htonl(twosK -> size);
    memcpy(mpintKdata, &mpintLenNetworkOrder, sizeof(uint32_t));
    memcpy(mpintKdata + sizeof(uint32_t), twosK -> data, twosK -> size);
    mpintK -> data = mpintKdata;
    mpintK -> size = twosK -> size + sizeof(uint32_t);

    RawByteArray *verificationMessage = concatenateVerificationMessage(dhResponse -> hostKeyType, dhResponse -> hostKeyTypeLen, dhResponse -> publicKey, dhResponse -> publicKeyLen, mpintK -> data, mpintK -> size);

    verifyServerSignature(dhResponse, verificationMessage);

    // cleanup (lots of free()'s and OSSL library free calls)
    
    return 0;
}

Function to generate K:
RawByteArray *generateSharedKey(EVP_PKEY *pkey, EVP_PKEY *peerkey) {
    RawByteArray *sharedKey = malloc(sizeof(RawByteArray));
    assert(sharedKey != NULL); 

    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
    unsigned char *skey;
    size_t skeylen;

    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, NULL);

    EVP_PKEY_derive_init(ctx);

    // Set peer's public key
    EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer(ctx, peerkey);

    // Determine buffer length for shared secret
    EVP_PKEY_derive(ctx, NULL, &skeylen);

    skey = OPENSSL_malloc(skeylen);
    assert(skey != NULL);

    // Derive the shared secret
    EVP_PKEY_derive(ctx, skey, &skeylen);

    sharedKey->data = skey;
    sharedKey->size = skeylen;

    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);

    return sharedKey;
}

Function to verify the server (I am not confident that the verification is carried out correctly, but I have verified that the hashing function is correct):
int verifyServerSignature(ServerDHResponse *dhResponse, RawByteArray *message) {
    EVP_PKEY *serverPublicKey = NULL;
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx = NULL;
    int ret = 0;

    // Load the server's EDDSA public key from raw byte array
    serverPublicKey = EVP_PKEY_new_raw_public_key(EVP_PKEY_ED25519, NULL, dhResponse -> publicKey, dhResponse -> publicKeyLen);
    if (serverPublicKey == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Could not load server's public key\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Check for Ed25519 key type
    int keyType = EVP_PKEY_base_id(serverPublicKey);
    if (keyType != EVP_PKEY_ED25519) {
        printf("Error: serverPublicKey is not of type Ed25519\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Create a digest context for verifying the signature
    mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    if (mdctx == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Could not create digest context\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Initialize the verification operation for Ed25519 (no digest needed)
    if (EVP_DigestVerifyInit(mdctx, NULL, NULL, NULL, serverPublicKey) != 1) {
        printf("Error: Could not initialize digest verify operation\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    RawByteArray *hashedMessage = computeSHA256Hash(message);
    printf("HASHED MESSAGE:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < hashedMessage -> size; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", hashedMessage -> data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    

    // Perform the verification using the server's signature (Ed25519 doesn't use DigestUpdate)
    if (EVP_DigestVerify(mdctx, dhResponse->hostSigData, dhResponse->hostSigDataLen, hashedMessage -> data, hashedMessage -> size) == 1) {
        printf("Server's signature verified successfully!\n");
        ret = 1;  // Signature is valid
    } else {
        printf("Error: Server's signature verification failed\n");
    }

    free(hashedMessage -> data);
    free(hashedMessage);

cleanup:
    if (mdctx) EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdctx);
    if (serverPublicKey) EVP_PKEY_free(serverPublicKey);

    return ret;
}

I haven't provided the code that concatenates the exchange message (that will become the exchange hash), but here is the output of that function:
V_C: 
00 00 00 0d 53 53 48 2d 32 2e 30 2d 6d 79 53 53 48 
V_S: 
00 00 00 1e 53 53 48 2d 32 2e 30 2d 4f 70 65 6e 53 53 48 5f 39 2e 37 70 31 20 44 65 62 69 61 6e 2d 37 
I_C: 
00 00 00 a1 c0 ca 55 cd e1 9d 71 40 6b 3f b0 95 be 6c c3 a3 00 00 00 1d 64 69 66 66 69 65 2d 68 65 6c 6c 6d 61 6e 2d 67 72 6f 75 70 31 34 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00 00 0b 73 73 68 2d 65 64 32 35 35 31 39 00 00 00 16 61 65 73 32 35 36 2d 67 63 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 00 00 00 16 61 65 73 32 35 36 2d 67 63 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 00 00 00 04 6e 6f 6e 65 00 00 00 04 6e 6f 6e 65 00 00 00 04 6e 6f 6e 65 00 00 00 04 6e 6f 6e 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
I_S: 
00 00 04 53 ed 98 e7 2f ec 27 a7 ca 52 ba 6e 1b 95 e8 49 70 00 00 01 31 73 6e 74 72 75 70 37 36 31 78 32 35 35 31 39 2d 73 68 61 35 31 32 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 63 75 72 76 65 32 35 35 31 39 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 2c 63 75 72 76 65 32 35 35 31 39 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 40 6c 69 62 73 73 68 2e 6f 72 67 2c 65 63 64 68 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 6e 69 73 74 70 32 35 36 2c 65 63 64 68 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 6e 69 73 74 70 33 38 34 2c 65 63 64 68 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 6e 69 73 74 70 35 32 31 2c 64 69 66 66 69 65 2d 68 65 6c 6c 6d 61 6e 2d 67 72 6f 75 70 2d 65 78 63 68 61 6e 67 65 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 2c 64 69 66 66 69 65 2d 68 65 6c 6c 6d 61 6e 2d 67 72 6f 75 70 31 36 2d 73 68 61 35 31 32 2c 64 69 66 66 69 65 2d 68 65 6c 6c 6d 61 6e 2d 67 72 6f 75 70 31 38 2d 73 68 61 35 31 32 2c 64 69 66 66 69 65 2d 68 65 6c 6c 6d 61 6e 2d 67 72 6f 75 70 31 34 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 2c 65 78 74 2d 69 6e 66 6f 2d 73 2c 6b 65 78 2d 73 74 72 69 63 74 2d 73 2d 76 30 30 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 00 00 00 39 72 73 61 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 35 31 32 2c 72 73 61 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 32 35 36 2c 65 63 64 73 61 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 6e 69 73 74 70 32 35 36 2c 73 73 68 2d 65 64 32 35 35 31 39 00 00 00 6c 63 68 61 63 68 61 32 30 2d 70 6f 6c 79 31 33 30 35 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 61 65 73 31 32 38 2d 63 74 72 2c 61 65 73 31 39 32 2d 63 74 72 2c 61 65 73 32 35 36 2d 63 74 72 2c 61 65 73 31 32 38 2d 67 63 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 61 65 73 32 35 36 2d 67 63 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 00 00 00 6c 63 68 61 63 68 61 32 30 2d 70 6f 6c 79 31 33 30 35 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 61 65 73 31 32 38 2d 63 74 72 2c 61 65 73 31 39 32 2d 63 74 72 2c 61 65 73 32 35 36 2d 63 74 72 2c 61 65 73 31 32 38 2d 67 63 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 61 65 73 32 35 36 2d 67 63 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 00 00 00 d5 75 6d 61 63 2d 36 34 2d 65 74 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 75 6d 61 63 2d 31 32 38 2d 65 74 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 68 6d 61 63 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 32 35 36 2d 65 74 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 68 6d 61 63 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 35 31 32 2d 65 74 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 68 6d 61 63 2d 73 68 61 31 2d 65 74 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 75 6d 61 63 2d 36 34 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 75 6d 61 63 2d 31 32 38 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 68 6d 61 63 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 32 35 36 2c 68 6d 61 63 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 35 31 32 2c 68 6d 61 63 2d 73 68 61 31 00 00 00 d5 75 6d 61 63 2d 36 34 2d 65 74 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 75 6d 61 63 2d 31 32 38 2d 65 74 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 68 6d 61 63 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 32 35 36 2d 65 74 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 68 6d 61 63 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 35 31 32 2d 65 74 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 68 6d 61 63 2d 73 68 61 31 2d 65 74 6d 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 75 6d 61 63 2d 36 34 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 75 6d 61 63 2d 31 32 38 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2c 68 6d 61 63 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 32 35 36 2c 68 6d 61 63 2d 73 68 61 32 2d 35 31 32 2c 68 6d 61 63 2d 73 68 61 31 00 00 00 15 6e 6f 6e 65 2c 7a 6c 69 62 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 00 00 00 15 6e 6f 6e 65 2c 7a 6c 69 62 40 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2e 63 6f 6d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
K_S: 
00 00 00 0b 73 73 68 2d 65 64 32 35 35 31 39 00 00 00 20 a3 33 20 e9 27 3e 17 9c 1e 4f e5 cf 9f d5 75 7b 9e 2f ae e7 1f 0f 7a c3 d2 67 f2 36 10 19 9e 7a 
E: 
00 00 01 00 36 30 cc 7a 37 2d 15 88 f6 0d dd 75 6b c9 de d9 ec 6c 1b ca bf 28 79 23 e1 8c e2 7c 4d cd 19 b1 4d 02 74 b5 78 70 7e 5e 46 fd 09 77 13 52 cc c3 ec 5c ea 95 53 d8 46 5e ee 7d a9 c3 2c 7a 3f 66 fb 4f 25 42 96 8a a4 6e 45 6b b7 ef 80 8b 9c 09 30 87 92 c7 02 7c 06 13 86 57 ed a4 a1 b1 29 f8 a1 55 61 d2 7d 59 78 93 69 0f 6f 46 18 85 05 32 8a d6 05 13 9f 6b 06 3a 79 fc 67 b9 1c 6f a6 fa d7 17 a4 de de 2a 46 98 42 ff 3c 79 bb c3 93 1b 4d 21 21 ad 56 42 eb 2f 65 cc 15 a0 da eb 5b 08 5e 9d e0 2e b0 49 72 13 2d 7b 75 08 da 76 d6 e6 23 16 3e 10 4a 11 89 15 ff 33 9a 5c f2 ad 7e e5 04 a7 52 89 12 f9 ee a4 81 7d c5 34 3c 64 21 62 f0 b2 c7 43 a2 11 13 c1 ad 83 a6 da 03 e3 8e 21 37 d5 35 3f 19 15 db d0 2f e0 ae 64 7e 59 e2 dd 0d 6f 1c cb a1 bc 0d cd 21 3e be 81 ae 35 de 9f 
F: 
00 00 01 01 00 a5 75 8f 39 4e 3e 65 7d 0a 80 75 d3 00 09 b1 b5 a0 43 3d 4a 1c 98 57 d9 d5 de 44 45 22 59 d8 80 f6 3a 21 c6 2f 60 29 6f e8 46 84 43 4e 47 da 3e 0e 01 20 30 bf 7f 08 6c 97 69 90 6a 62 d2 94 c3 d1 db 2a 9e 1f 33 55 53 5b d6 a9 da 64 3a 8e 59 be 2e a9 c6 a8 df c8 0f 54 1c 27 c4 a6 d7 b4 b4 6b d4 70 bf 0d 93 da 04 29 e9 90 d9 20 a4 6d 88 50 f0 3f 0a 03 f5 20 6c 9c fe d7 c3 a6 3c 30 db cf 77 94 ec f1 16 1f 3d 53 bf 4c 6c 48 e0 63 2f 04 2c 0b 0c e9 0b c8 43 90 87 5b b1 82 83 f1 f6 65 71 93 a0 74 86 1f 25 1f 5a 8e 3b 22 d2 5e 23 96 49 d8 31 3d c5 be 4c 8d db 03 01 5a fa ba bb 86 b2 44 e5 2c 2b 15 7d 5a 36 88 87 d9 75 b9 5b 1c 78 59 00 ae c8 1a 1e 3d 35 37 11 aa 05 8f 80 d0 5a af 0b 16 58 7b e1 ec d8 54 84 8b ac ef ce 1d d9 9f ca 2a 9c 1c 24 c3 91 b5 68 d5 c2 a6 65 
K: 
00 00 01 00 70 a5 c8 9e 04 00 65 3c 96 15 a9 b4 a2 eb 52 10 39 8e 07 92 2f 14 67 7d a8 61 30 aa e6 db a6 1f 39 d9 54 db 42 65 35 f3 6c cf 46 3e a4 85 ba c3 e6 66 f1 e2 cf 12 44 8a af d4 48 d3 bf a7 95 d5 b2 45 80 f7 86 b5 f7 96 fa 93 d3 6b 18 85 4f 9c 3c 3c cc 2b 2c b4 f1 55 22 78 20 c5 fc 99 db 04 98 98 49 88 44 56 1d 3e e1 71 62 45 d3 f8 b4 6f 53 6b e2 8c 5d 4f 44 55 57 fe 29 a8 5a 0a 09 fe 94 7e 00 7e 54 7b b8 5f 06 ca b9 1a ff 1e e6 b3 70 32 a4 4e 6f 53 02 34 60 b4 31 a8 5d d0 c2 e6 a6 18 0e 58 38 0f 1d 65 7f 4a 68 64 82 fd d9 f7 28 d6 d8 75 0b cf a5 e2 b8 9b a1 bc 03 b2 55 9d d0 f6 fc 95 ab 70 ca 1a d3 32 55 ae b7 2d 59 83 c7 1b 6f 1b a7 6a 6c 20 16 c0 b3 73 de 7a cc d1 d8 c8 1f e5 e5 0f 9b 70 cb b0 7e 3a 2c 3d fe 2a f7 f0 eb 71 ee 26 48 8d 2c 47 a3 cb bb ea 6c 0d 
HASHED MESSAGE:
e4 f0 46 38 4a 36 a9 6a f9 50 26 ea 79 b4 21 45 d5 35 8c 12 40 b2 89 cd ae 00 19 1c a9 c7 4e b8 
Error: Server's signature verification failed

Note, the last 2 sections (HASHED MESSAGE and Error) are printed within the verifyServerSignature function. This output looks right to me from using Wireshark to compare bytes, but I may be misunderstanding the correct form, or just missing a mistake.
If I've missed a relevant section of code, here's the entire C file.
I think that I have encoded the items that form the message that will be hashed to create the exchange hash correctly, but I may still be missing something.
I have checked the items' endian-ness, and I think all are in big endian, except for K which I am not sure the endian-ness of (but I have tried passing it in as it returned from the OSSL function and with its endian-ness swapped, neither form makes the verification pass, so I know it's not the only issue).
I'm not confident that I am using the OpenSSL functions to correctly verify the server, so any suggestions on how to debug the verification process better would be appreciated.
